# Is there a situation where any intersection of upward-closed subset is not upward-closed(can be infinite)?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, lattice-orders, domain-theory

In any quasi-ordered set X, we say that a subset A is upward-closed iff whenever $x\in A \ $and$\ x \leqslant y$, then $y\in A$.

Consider the collection $\mathcal{O}$ of all upward closed subsets of $X$. This is a
topology. (In Non-Hausdorff Topology and Domain Theory by Jean Goubault-Larrecq.P57),
I must admit it's obvious.(1. $X,\emptyset$ is upward closed; 2. for every $x\in \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}U_\alpha$, $x \leqslant y$ $\exists \alpha _0\in I$ s.t. $x\in U_\alpha$ ($U_\alpha$ is upward closed subsets of $X$), $y\in U_\alpha \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}U_\alpha$; 3. for every $x\in 
 \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}U_i$, $x\in U_i$ ($\forall 1\leqslant i \leqslant n$), $y\in U_i$ ($\forall 1\leqslant i \leqslant n$), $y\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}U_i$).

My question is whether there is a situation where any intersection of  upward-closed subset is not upward-closed(can be infinite)? If so, how should it be constructed?

Comment: No.  Upward-closed is closed under arbitrary intersections and unions, similarly downward-closed.

Comment: You are totally right, just use definition can simply proof it.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your title. The grammar is off.

Comment: The title makes no sense.

Comment: so sorry for that, I've corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not. Characterization by a pre/quasi-order is the [Alexandrov](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000090) property, equivalent to the arbitrary intersection of open being open.